# Switching text and hrefs depending on scroll location with JS

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have a page with a lot of text that requires some amount of scrolling.  I was able to get a button, when clicked, to shoot to the top of the page I am on.  But when at the top of the page, I am wanting this button to switch to another link that goes to the homepage.

Bonus Points:  How would I change the text to also switch from "top" to "home"?  I have not tackled this hurdle because I figured my issue with switching the href would correlate to this obstacle.

JS:

```
window.onscroll = function() { scrollFunction() };

function scrollFunction() {
    document.getElementById("scroll-to-top-button").classList.toggle("show");
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
            window.location = "#top";
        } else if(document.body.scrollTop = 0){
            window.location.href = "https://homepage.html";
        }
    }
}
```

html:

```
<a href="" class="scroll-to-top-button active" onclick="scrollFunction()" data-smooth-scroll=""><div class="fas fa-angle-up">top</div></a>
```

I have tried using window.scrollY instead of .scrollTop - but I have not touched scrolling elements prior to this.  I am a little fuzzy with how to indicate if I have scrolled vs not scrolled.  I do not know if my issue is because my if, else elements are not correct - or if it is something else?

Comment: You're adding tens of click listeners per second every time you scroll the page. You've to pull the `window.onclick = ...` out of the scroll listener. Or actually, you've to pull everything out of the scroll handler.

Comment: Great questions. For bonus points, let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Is Your button/anchor element have a position of fixed? if not why don't you take two different button/anchor to toggle from top to bottom and bottom to top?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small code snippet example to answer your question,

```js
const anchor = document.querySelector('a') 



window.addEventListener('scroll',() => {
  if(window.scrollY > 100){
    anchor.setAttribute('href', "#above")
    anchor.innerText = "go above"

  }else{
    anchor.setAttribute('href', "#below")
    anchor.innerText = "go below"

  }
})
```

```css
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
header{
  background: white;
  width: 100%
}
#above{
  height:100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
#below{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
  <header style="position:fixed">    
  <a href="#below">go below</a>
  </header>
  
  <section id="above"></section>
  <section id="below"></section>
```

Here I am using **setAttribute()** to change the href attribute of anchor tag, and **innerText** to change that same anchor tag's text. I am using **scrollY** to check amount of window scrolled.

You could change the **if(window.scrollY > 'change this value')** according to your need